# Don't works header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

Tags: php, excel

I have a server that is working correctly with these headers:

```
header ("Content-Type: application / vnd.ms-excel");
header ("content-disposition: attachment; filename = NAME.xls");
```

By taking it to another server, the file is NOT downloaded, but it is presented on the screen as one more page.

The problem is that I do not know what configuration I should adjust.

Can someone help me?

Comment: If you say it's an Excel file, some browsers may try and open it directly in the browser. Try sending it as `application/octet-stream` to make it "dumb data".

Comment: Hello, transman!
It is a system that is migrating from one server to another, I can not make changes.
Both servers have the same configurations (according to the system administrator).
The system opens a new page to ask the user where the file will be downloaded. On the original server, that is done (with Chrome or Mozilla). On the "copy" server, the excel is opened as a page (with Chrome or Mozilla), it does not question the user whether he wants to download it or not.
That's why I need to find what configuration I must move to verify with the administrator the parameters.